# How can I do a redirect from a plugin in Django CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a form in a plugin that on submit I need to redirect to another page.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

**So possible solutions are:**

1. Use an App-Hook
2. Throw an exception in your plugin render method that would be caught by a middleware class and do the redirect from there.
3. Create a middleware class and during the "process_response" method check for a value on the request object that was added during the render method of the plugin then do the redirect.

Comment: Its a custom plugin that renders a form.

Comment: Ok, so you'd need to also hook your page to the view that handles the POST via a CMS App Hook. Then you will be able to do your redirect.

Comment: Was afraid of that. From what I've researched only other solution is to throw an exception in the plugin and catch it in a middleware class. Either that or add something to the request and use middleware somewhere after rendering to do the redirect.

Comment: Well, when your plugin renders the form, can you not just point the form action to the view you want then handle the redirect from there? One option would be to do an ajax submission of the form, and then handle the redirect client-side. Then you don't have to have an app-hook.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are not really suitable for processing POST requests and there's no way to influence the HTTP Response object from a plugin (other than the content of that response).

The reason Plugins have no hook to process POST requests is that a single page is usually composed of several plugins, and figuring out which plugin should handle the POST request would be very hard. For the same reason they can't change the response, since two plugins could try to change the response in an incompatible fashion.

The solution for this is to have a dedicated POST endpoint for your plugins (either static via urlpatterns or via an Apphook). That endpoint would then redirect to another page, or the page the form is on, so the plugin would send some data with it. Alternatively the plugin submits the form via AJAX to that endpoint and redirects/acts in javascript.